# Accordion adjusting height of the panels in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, accordion

I am trying to stop autoresize accordion panel by using this script

```
$( "#fullpageaccordion .questions" ).accordion({autoHeight: false});
```

which does not work - accordion adjust the content area size by its largest content.
What I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Version of jQuery UI?

Comment: I believe 1.8.2 - however I am not sure )))

Comment: Look in the top of the file?

Comment: Yeh that's what I did))))

Comment: By the way, is a big difference to use 1.9.0 over 1.8.2? Shall I update?

Comment: You could try upgrading because autoHeight: false has been replaced with heightStyle: content so there was probably a good reason for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jQuery 1.9.0
`$( "#fullpageaccordion .questions" ).accordion({heightStyle: "content"});`
In jQuery 1.8.2
You are correct--
`$( "#fullpageaccordion .questions" ).accordion({autoHeight: false});`
[Reference](https://api.jqueryui.com/1.8/accordion/#option-autoHeight)

Comment: Nope((( does not. Accordion is defined by this <div class="questions">

Comment: `$(".questions").accordion({autoHeight: false});` have you tried this

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
$('#accordion').accordion({
   collapsible: true,
   autoHeight: false
});
```

Or try this to clear height...

```
$('#accordion').accordion({ 
   clearStyle: true 
});
```

Note: autoHeight doesnt work with clearStyle

Comment: Try http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.7/docs/accordion.html#option-clearStyle